# Execution failed for task ':website:buildDockerImage'. using gradlew build of apache beam

Tags: docker, gradle, apache-beam

I need to build apache beam using gradle . `./gradlew build` . However, I got the following error :
`Execution failed for task ':website:buildDockerImage'. > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'docker''`

java version : openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
gradle version : Gradle 5.4
By using `--info` , I got the following :

```
Caching disabled for task ':website:buildDockerImage' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
Task ':website:buildDockerImage' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Starting process 'command 'docker''. Working directory: /home/namenode/beam/website Command: docker build -t beam-website .
:website:buildDockerImage (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 20,5,main]) completed. Took 0.018 secs.
Closing Git repo: /home/namenode/beam/.git
Closing Git repo: /home/namenode/beam/.git

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':website:buildDockerImage'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'docker''
```

while --stacktrace outputs :

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':website:buildDockerImage'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:198)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
        ...  more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/home/namenode/beam/website"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        ... 8 more

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
[root@namenode beam]# ./gradlew build
Watching the file system is not supported on this operating system.
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
> Task :website:buildDockerImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':website:buildDockerImage'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'docker''
```

how can I proceed ?

Comment:  Welcome to Stackoverlow! You may run the build with flags `--info` and `--stacktrace` to get more information on the root cause of your issue. Also, you may attach relevant information here.

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: Thanks! What about `--stacktrace`?

Comment: by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/home/namenode/beam/website"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        ... 8 more

Comment: Dump question, is Docker actually installed on your machine?

Comment: I installed docker but I got now the following error : Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM debian:stretch-slim
Pulling repository debian
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/debian/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

> Task :website:buildDockerImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':website:buildDockerImage'.
> Process 'command 'docker'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Sounds like you are building in an air-gapped environment and cannot reach `index.docker.io`